# Curl doesn't work in crontab

Tags: unix, curl, cron

I'm new to set up server settings and to the whole unix thing so maybe this is simple.

I'm trying to start crontab with curl in but it doesn't work. I want it go to file and send email every 30 minutes.

If just writing

```
curl http://webaddress.com/controller/action
```

in the terminal everything works just fine and it will send out mail as I want.

But when I trying to do it with crontab it never "kicks".
In the crontab -e I have write

```
0,30 * * * * curl http://webaddress.com/controller/action
```

I have also tried

```
0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://webaddress.com/controller/action
```

nothing with result.

Anyone have any clue what can be wrong?

**SOLVED**

It was some PAM related bug on the server.
To fix it I wrote:

```
aptitude reinstall libpam-modules libpam0g cron
```

Comment: try add -v option to see details?

Answer (score 0):

Check that everything for PAM is installed. ;-)